# regarding the url link to download specific tensorflow version

Tags: tensorflow

When installing [tensorflow,](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux#the_url_of_the_tensorflow_python_package) sometimes I need to install specific versions, which need to be directly downloaded from the source.

For instance, this URL link

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-1.8.0-cp34-cp34m-linux_x86_64.whl
```

so if I need one, like version 1.6, for windows, etc, how to get the related address. I can infer the address, but are there any list be officially posted?

I also tried the following approaches, both of which failed

```
(detection) C:\Users>conda install tensorflow-cpu==1.5.0
Fetching package metadata .............

PackageNotFoundError: Packages missing in current channels:

  - tensorflow-cpu ==1.5.0

We have searched for the packages in the following channels:

  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/win-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2/noarch

(detection) C:\Users\>pip install --upgrade tensorflow-cpu==1.5.0
Collecting tensorflow-cpu==1.5.0
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-cpu==1.5.0 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow-cpu==1.5.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For python, most of the time you install Tensorflow from a package manager, which is able to install earlier versions.

E.g. if you are using `pip`, use

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu==1.2.1
```

if you are using `conda`,

```
conda install tensorflow-gpu==1.2.1
```

Of course replace `1.2.1` with the version you want (not so many available with `conda`), `tensorflow-gpu` with `tensorflow` if you are after the CPU-only version, also `pip` with `pip3` on some systems if you are using python 3.

Comment: Hi, I also tried your suggestions, but they failed. Would you like to take a look at it? I updated my original post. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, as I said in my answer, `conda` does not have all versions of tensorflow. `pip` is your best chance if you have precise requirements.

Comment: Can you elaborate what are the precise requirement look like? For example, I already specified tensorflow-cpu=1.5.0

Comment: As I said, `conda` does not have all tensorflow versions. `conda search -f tensorflow-gpu`  will give you available versions.